# Is $T(\ell^1 ) \subseteq \ell^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If we have a linear operator $(\ell^{\infty} , \|\cdot \|_{\infty} ) \rightarrow (\ell^{\infty} , \|\cdot \|_{\infty} ) $

by $T((a_k)_{k \ge 1}) = (b_k)_{k \ge 1}$ where $$ b_k= \frac{a_1+...+a_k}{k}$$

Is $T(\ell^1 ) \subseteq \ell^1$?

---

Since $(a_k)$ is in the infinity norm and since $\ell ^p \subseteq \ell^q $, we have $(a_k) \in \ell^1$ right? So $\sum |a_k| < \infty$ so there exists $N$ such that $|a_k|<1 $ for all $k \ge N$. So this holds for $|a_k|/k<1$ too so $\sum |b_k| < \infty$ too? So we can say that it is a subset of $\ell^1$?

Comment: Did you mean $b_k= \frac{a_1+...+a_k}{k}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It fails for the sequence $1,0,0,\dots $

Comment: In fact if $(a_n)$ is any non-negative sequence, then $(\,(a_1 + \cdots + a_n)/n\,)$ is never in $l^1,$ unless all $a_n =  0.$

Answer (score 1):

Pick $a_k = \frac{1}{2^k}$. Then
$$
b_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{n}\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\bigg) > \frac{1}{2n},
$$
so $\sum b_n$ diverges